# A question on sentence structure

Tags: grammaire, traduction

How do I accurately translate a sentence like "being fast is not important but being accurate is."?

I feel like "être rapide n'est pas important mais être précis est" is wrong, especially with the ending on a "est".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is indeed an issue with the ending.

> *Être rapide n'est pas important mais être précis **l'** est.* (no space after the *apostrophe*<sup>1</sup>)

or in more idiomatic ways :

> *Ce n'est pas être rapide qui est important, c'est être précis.*

> *Ce n'est pas la vitesse qui compte, c'est la précision.*

<sup>1</sup>  <sub>For some reason, the editor provided by Stack Exchange doesn't seem to allow a bolded apostrophe immediately followed by a non-space character.</sub>